# text-decoration underline исключив псевдоэлемент?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы нижнее подчеркивание не касалось псевдоэлемента?
То есть чтобы не подчеркивался символ "/" ?

```
.uploader span{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.uploader span:before{
    content: ' / '
}
.uploader span:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
}

<div class="uploader">
      <span>Папка 0</span>
      <span>Папка 1</span>
      <span>Папка 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я адепт БЭМ, поэтому сделал бы как-нибудь так:

```css
.uploader__item{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}

.uploader__item:hover .uploader__folder {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.uploader__item:before{
    content: ' / '
}
```

```html
<div class="uploader">
      <div class="uploader__item">
        <span class="uploader__folder">Папка 0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="uploader__item">
        <span class="uploader__folder">Папка 1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="uploader__item">
        <span class="uploader__folder">Папка 2</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавил html код

Comment: @manking Обновил ответ